# Find the maximum sum of a tree in python

Tags: python, tree

I have a tree of numbers that I want to be able to find the sum of numbers. Below each number are two children to the left and right Of all the possible paths, I want to be able to find the biggest number through all the possible paths. Here is an example

```
       8
   3      11
10   2  32  6
```

returns 8+11+32=51

I feel that this is a recursion problem but I am stuck with my code and keep getting errors. I think that I am approaching this incorrectly. Below is my code:

```
# Returns root key value
def getRootValue(root):
    return root

# Returns reference to left child
def getLeftChild(root):
    value=None
    if root.leftChild!=None:
        value=root.leftChild
    return value

# Returns reference to right child
def getRightChild(root):
    value=None
    if root.rightChild!=None:
        value = root.rightChild
    return value

def sum_of_branch(root):
    sum=0  
if root.getLeftChild() ==None and root.getRightChild()==None:
    return rounds
else:
    rounds+=rounds+1
    keys_sum[depth]=sum+root.key
    return sum_to_deepest(root.left), sum_to_deepest(root.right)
    if root.getLeftChild()!=None:
        rounds+=root.getLeftChild().branchLenSum()
    if root.getRightChild()!=None:
        rounds+=root.getRightChild().branchLenSum()
    return rounds
```

Comment: can you include the full code ? including the structure of each node and also sum_to_deepest function

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the data structure you are using is difficult to give you an answer. But I think you are looking for somenthing like this:

> ```
> def sum_of_branch(root):
>     # If it has not childs we have arrived at the end of the tree.
>     # We return the value of this child.
>     if root.getLeftChild() ==None and root.getRightChild()==None:
>         return getRootValue(root)
>     else:
>         # If it has children we calculate the sum of each branch. 
>         leftSum = sum_of_branch(root.getLeftChild())
>         rightSum = sum_of_branch(root.getRightChild())
>         # And return the maximun of them.
>         if leftSum > rightSum:
>             return getRootValue(root) + leftSum
>         else:
>             return getRootValue(root) + rightSum
> ```