# Maximum sum of a tree in Scheme

Tags: recursion, tree, scheme

I am having troubles with an exercise I am trying to do because I'm new to this language and to think in a recursive way is kind of hard to me. I have a tree (not neccesary binary) and I need to find the path that gives the maximum sum. For example I have the tree: ’(1 ((0) (2 ((3) (2))) (5))) given in the image

[Example tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoFnB.png)

```
        1
  0     2     5
      3   2
```

So I have to do a function: (function ’(1 ((0) (2 ((3) (2))) (5)))) and it should return 6 (in this case). There are 2 paths that give the answer: 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 and 1 + 5 = 6. I tried to "translate" a code in python [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953446/find-the-maximum-sum-of-a-tree-in-python), but I have no idea how to do it recursively in Scheme.

Comment: Any list structure can bee seen as a binary tree with cons and nil as nodes and everything else as values, but for everything else you better provide `value`, `children`, `empty-tree`,  and `make-tree` and perhaps `tree?`. Basically if you do this an implementation can change from lists to vectors and it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion is pretty simple, you just need to check 3 cases:

```
NUMBER?
NULL?
PAIR?
```

So in scheme you would structure it like this:

```
(define (tree-sum t)
  (cond ((number? t)
         ...)
        ((null? t)
         ...)
        ((pair? t)
         ...)))
```

The `pair?` one is the recursive case in which you add up the sums of car and cdr. Hope that helps!

Comment: but they interpret their tree differently. under your interpretation 5 goes under 2 and the maximum path sums up to 8.